# Sort images in a container

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, swipe

I have 50 images and i want to sort these images in one "xaml" page. 
User should be able to swipe images up and down .
What is the best tool for this action.
Also are there any easy way to put 50 images .

Answer (score 0):

This ReorderListBox may be exactly what your are looking for http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2010/12/27/a-reorderlistbox-for-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: actually i misexplain my problem i want to put multiple images in image tool how can i do that